# Program accepts non-numeric input, how do I get it to stop doing that?

Tags: c++

A particular talent competition has five judges, each of whom awards a score between 0 and 10 (both 0 and 10 are considered valid!) to each performer. Fractional scores, such as 8.3, are allowed. A performer’s final score is determined by dropping the highest and lowest score received, then averaging the three remaining scores.

Write a program that uses these rules to calculate and display a contestant’s score. It should include the following functions:

`void getJudgeData()` . This function should ask the user for a judge’s score, store it in a reference parameter variable, and validate it. This function should be called by main once for each of the five judges.Make the following change to `void getJudgeData( )`.

The function should take in 2 parameters, not 1, as specified above

The first parameter should be a string that holds the values "Judge 1", "Judge 2".. and so on.

The second parameter should follow specifications shown above.

The `getJudgeData` function should ensure that:

score is numeric

score is >= 0

score is <= 10

`double getHighest()`. This function takes in 5 scores and returns the highest of the 5 parameters passed into it.

`double getLowest()`. This function takes in 5 scores and returns the lowest of the 5 parameters passed into it.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void getJudgeData(string jname, double &score); 
double getAverage(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5);
double  findLowest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score);
double  findHighest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5);

int main()
{
    //Variables
    double score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, average, lowest, highest;

    //Get input from five judges
    std::cout << "Enter the scores for the five judges." << endl;
    getJudgeData("Judge 1", score1);
    getJudgeData("Judge 2", score2);
    getJudgeData("Judge 3", score3);
    getJudgeData("Judge 4", score4);
    getJudgeData("Judge 5", score5);

    average = getAverage(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    lowest = findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);
    highest = findHighest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

/* getJudgeData
** Function should ask the user for a judge's score, store it in a reference parameter variable, and validate it.
This function should be called by main once for each of the five judges.
*/
void getJudgeData(string jname, double &score)
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Data entry for Judge. Score must be in the range 0 - 10: ";
        cin >> score;
        if (!cin)
        {
            cout << "Invalid. Input must be numeric. Please re-enter score." << std::endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            if (score < 0 || score > 10)
            {
                cout << "Invalid. Score must be between 0 and 10. Please re-enter score." << std::endl;
            }
        }
    } while (!cin || score < 0 || score > 10);

}

/* calcScore 
Function should calculate and return the average of the three scores
that remain after dropping the highest and lowest scores.
*/
double getAverage(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    double lowest,
        highest,
        average;

    //Find lowest
    lowest = findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);

    //Find highest
    highest = findHighest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);

    //Calculate average
    average = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - highest - lowest) / 3;

    //std::cout << std::setprecision(3) << "Average: " << scoreAverage << std::endl;
    cout << setprecision(3) << "Average: " << average << endl;
    cout << setprecision(3) << "Lowest: " << lowest << endl;
    cout << setprecision(3) << "Highest: " << highest << endl;

    return average;
}


//findLowest
double findLowest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    //Compare and return low score
    if (score1 < score2 && score1 < score3 && score1 < score4 && score1 < score5)
    {
        return score1;
    }
    else if (score2 < score1 && score2 < score3 && score2 < score4 && score2 < score5)
    {
        return score2;
    }
    else if (score3 < score2 && score3 < score1 && score3 < score4 && score3 < score5)
    {
        return score3;
    }
    else if (score4 < score2 && score4 < score3 && score4 < score1 && score4 < score5)
    {
        return score4;
    }
    else
    {
        return score5;
    }
}

//findHighest
double findHighest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    //Compare and return low score
    if (score1 > score2 && score1 > score3 && score1 > score4 && score1 > score5)
    {
        return score1;
    }
    else if (score2 > score1 && score2 > score3 && score2 > score4 && score2 > score5)
    {
        return score2;
    }
    else if (score3 > score2 && score3 > score1 && score3 > score4 && score3 > score5)
    {
        return score3;
    }
    else if (score4 > score2 && score4 > score3 && score4 > score1 && score4 > score5)
    {
        return score4;
    }
    else
    {
        return score5;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the program accepts non-numeric input, how do I get it to stop doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you reset error flag of `std::cin`, and then check for error again in. You might change to something like:

```
void getJudgeData(string jname, double &score)
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Data entry for Judge. Score must be in the range 0 - 10: ";
        cin >> score;
        if (!cin)
        {
            score = -1; // Invalid value to force the loop
            cout << "Invalid. Input must be numeric. Please re-enter score." << std::endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else if (score < 0 || score > 10)
        {
            cout << "Invalid. Score must be between 0 and 10. Please re-enter score.\n";
        }
    } while (score < 0 || score > 10);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4r8M7x)

Comment: Thanks now it seems to be working. Also is there a way I can make it so you can see which judge it's asking for input from?

Comment: `std::cout << "Data entry for " << jname << ". Score must be in the range 0 - 10: ";`